# How do I delete a city to restart from zero?

Tags: simcity-2013

The question is pretty simple, but I can't find the answer. I made a terrible city and now I'm looking for a way to restart my city (delete and start from scratch) without leaving my region as my friends are playing as well and I like my neighborhood cities.

Abandoning it just leaves the city, but I want to restart.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your other option is to bulldoze everything. I do not think you can "restart" your city at all. i.e. still own it, start with $50K and nothing built. So save up $50K then use the de-zone selection and the bulldozer to wipe it all out.